# How to append dynamically generated values into NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to add some dynamically calculated values to result array:

```
out = []
for item in foo:
    spam = get_spam(foo)
    out.append(spam)
return np.array(out)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because **spam** shape is (10,1) and **out** array has one extra dimension - this is bad.

I did something like this:

```
for index, item in enumerate(foo):
    spam = get_spam(foo)
    if index == 0:
        out = spam
    else:
        out = np.append(out, spam, 1)
return out
```

But this solution is not short, easy, and readable.

How do this in pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy `concatenate` function:

```
np.concatenate([get_spam(foo) for item in foo])
```

It eventually accepts an argument *axes* for the direction of concatenation (vertically/horizontally).

Comment: what if I have a long **for** cycle body?

Comment: you mean your list is really really long and it takes time? you can use map reduce concept and split foo, perform this operation on one core each and then recombine.

Comment: Repeated `np.append` is inefficient.  Use list append, and finish with `concatenate`.

Answer (score 1):

if **spam** always has the shape (10,1) you could slice the returned array with `[:,0]`

```
for item in foo:
    spam = get_spam(foo)
    out.append(spam[:,0])
return np.array(out)
```

Comment: **spam** has not always shape (10,1)